# CUPS: "Local name collision."

Tags: printing

I'm seeing this error over and over in my cups error log in /var/log/cups/error_log

```
DNS-SD registration of "Printer Description" failed: Local name collision.
```

What is causing this error? What can I do on my ubuntu server to prevent it?

Comment: Is there more than one printer hooked up? Is the printer hooked up by both wireless and wired connections? You can run `lpstat -p` from the terminal and add that to your post by editing it.

Comment: Yes there are over 300 printers connected, all IP based.

Comment: From my reading, that is caused by printers having the same description. Which printers those are, or exactly how to fix them, I do not know.